# Exercise on finding nilpotent elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, nilpotence

Task: Find the nilpotents in $\mathbb{Z}/\langle n\rangle$. In particular, take $n=12$.

Solution: An element $m$ is nilpotent $\bmod{n}$ iff $n|m^k$. So $nil(R)=\{0,6\}$.

My question about this solution (provided in textbook) may be some rookie mistake. My first intuition before consulting the solution is that I need to find the order of each element under the group operation of addition. I got $nil(\mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z})=\{0,1,2,3,4,6,8,9,10\}$. I got this by trying to compute $a*b\equiv 0 \mod{12},\, a,b,\in \mathbb{Z}/12\mathbb{Z}$.

The given solution makes sense to me except for the part where $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ is an additive group and not multiplication. Could someone explain why this is for me please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question is about the *multiplicative* structure, not the additive structure. An element $a$ of a **ring** is nilpotent if there exists $k\gt 0$ such that $a^k=0$ (note how you are using both a multiplicative structure, by talking about $a^k$, and an additive structure, by talking about $0$). We don't talk about "nilpotent elements" in groups; we talk about *torsion* elements, and this question is not about that. Since $\mathbb{Z}$ is a **ring** and $\langle n\rangle$ is an ideal, $\mathbb{Z}/\langle n\rangle$ is a **ring**.

Comment: Surely this question, coming from a textbook, is from the section of the book on rings, not the section on groups.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin Thank you for making that distinction. Does this mean that I should resort to multiplication when I see the word "nilpotent" from here on out? (and "torsion" with addition?) I see my confused stems from learning about the modulo groups in group theory. My bad for not seeing it as a ring.

Comment: "Nilpotent element" is a ring-theory term. There are other places where the word has other meanings (you can talk about "nilpotent groups" and "nilpotent Lie algebras", for example). But when you talk about nilpotent **element**, as far as I know it always means that some power of it equals $0$.

Comment: That helps! thank you :)